# Change order content blocks home page

Tags: templating, order, content, blocks

Good afternoon, I was wondering to what extent you can change (the order for example) the existing contentblocks on the pages. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

By default, Matrix blocks will display in the order you have entered them in your entry form.

If you need to change the display order, you can drag/drop your blocks straight from your entry form using the small handle on the right of the blocks and the order will be reflected on your page.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am pretty new to this, so can you make a screenshot of an example of an entry form? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the screenshot below and as Oli already mentioned, you can simply drag the content blocks on a page and hit the save button. That said, this is possible with contentblocks that are in a [matrixfield](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/matrix-fields.html). If you have regular fields for your page, you will need to arrange them in the section setup. Only matrix block elements can be arranged differently for every page.

[image]